# download files from the internet using urllib issue

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to download data files from a website using urllib.

My code is

```
import urllib
url_common = 'http://apps.waterconnect.sa.gov.au/SiteInfo/Data/Site_Data/'
site_list=['4260514','4260512','4260519']
parameter_list=['ecrec','ecday','flowrec','flowcday']
for site in site_list:
    for parameter in parameter_list:        
        try:
            url = url_common+'A'+site+'/'+'a'+site+'_'+parameter+'.zip'
            urllib.urlretrieve(url,'A'+site+'_'+parameter+'.zip')
        except ValueError:
            break
```

My issue is some sites do not have all the parameter files. For eg, with my code, site 1 doesn't have flowcday but python still creates the zip file with nothing in content. How can I stop python to create these files if there's no data?

Many thanks,

Comment: You could issue a HEAD request before attempting to download.  You could also use `urlopen` and check the content size when doing a `read()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe `urllib2.urlopen` is more suitable in this situation.

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import URLError

url_common = 'http://apps.waterconnect.sa.gov.au/SiteInfo/Data/Site_Data/'
site_list=['4260514','4260512','4260519']
parameter_list=['ecrec','ecday','flowrec','flowcday']
for site in site_list:
    for parameter in parameter_list:        
        try:
            url = url_common+'A'+site+'/'+'a'+site+'_'+parameter+'.zip'
            name ='A'+site+'_'+parameter+'.zip'
            req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            with open(name,'wb') as fh:
                fh.write(req.read())
        except URLError,e:
            if e.code==404:
                print name + '  not found. moving on...'
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just some comments: I move the line (name=....) above urllib2.urlopen so that it prints out the right error message. And I change open(name,'w') to open(name,'wb') as I am using windows.